# What is the procedure to specify a random effects design matrix?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, linear-model

I am trying to figure out the procedure for design matrix specification for mixed effect models, and I already know how to create the fixed effects design matrix.

However, I have recently been working on a procedure for making the random effects design matrix, and wanted to post it as a question here, to get feedback on it.

*Note that I purposely exclude numerical predictors for now, since (it seems to me) random effects predictors are often categorical.*

*Also, I am ignoring explicit specification of covariance structures (as can be done with the lmer() function from lme4), since I don't know anything about covariance.*

I feel like specifying the random effects design matrix is too easy, since there is no baseline column (column of 1's) and every predictor level gets a column no matter what, i.e. regardless of whether the predictor is non-nested or nested.

So...is the procedure described below correct for making the random effects design matrix for a mixed model?

### Procedure to Specify a Random Effects Design Matrix (for use in Mixed Model)

***Step 1 - Simple Effects of Categorical Predictors***
A categorical unordered predictor of any type, either crossed, nesting, or nested, has (P) simple effect columns, where P is equal to the number of levels of the predictor. For each column, write 1's for the data points that are associated with that column's level.

***Step 2 - Two-Way Interactions***
For every pair of simple effect columns between different predictors, multiply them together. This could be two random effect predictors, or a random effect predictor with a fixed effect predictor.

***Step 3 - Three-way Interactions***
For every trio of simple effect columns between different predictors, multiply them together.

Answer (score 6):

The random effects in mixed-effects models are used to account for correlations in grouped/cluster data. The two main settings of such data are *multilevel* and *longitudinal* designs or combinations of these two.

- In multilevel designs, the study participants are organized in a number of nested or non-nested clusters. For example, students in schools, and schools in districts (nested design), or students in schools and students in sports clubs (non-nested). The premise is that measurements from participants in the same cluster are more correlated than measurements from participants in different clusters.
- In longitudinal designs, the cluster is the participant, and we collect repeated measurements over time for a number of variables. Measurements from the same participant will be serially correlated.

The design of your study, multilevel, longitudinal, or a mix of the two, will dictate an initial assumption for the random-effects design matrix. In multilevel designs, you typically start with a random intercept per level, and in longitudinal data, you want to include functions of time in the random effects design matrix to account for the serial correlations. In many cases, the random effects structure that is implied from the design of the study is not supported by the data you have, leading to overly complex models and convergence problems. Hence, the general advice is to start with a simple random effects structure and build it up, evaluating each step using likelihood ratio tests.

Comment: Thanks Dimitris! I understand your points, I think for me it's just that I am purposefully approaching the problem of how to specify mixed model design matrices from the dataset side, instead of the descriptive side. The reason I am trying this is b/c of the issue you mention about the design not being supported by the dataset. My thesis is that is should be possible to specify the correct design matrices for a mixed model just using the structure of the data and nothing else...(1/2)

Comment: ...For example, you mention multilevel and longitudinal designs, but there may be a dataset-driven way of looking at these designs, of which there are three variations. Variant 1 - the multilevel nested design uses nested categorical predictors. Variant 2 - the multilevel non-nested design uses non-nested categorical predictors. Variant 3 - the longitudinal design uses a categorical predictor (participant) with a numerical predictor (time). These different predictor type (categorical vs. numerical) and data structures (non-nested vs. nested) should drive des. matrix specification I think (2/2)

Comment: Addendum - Design matrix specification can't rely solely on the dataset, namely the predictor type (categorical vs. numerical) and the dataset structure (non-nested vs. nested), because the predictor randomness type (fixed effects vs. random effects) must be identified by the experimenter using qualitative information that is not present within the dataset itself