# Mixed effects modelling - Is there a limit for number of observations?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, convergence

I started working on some linear mixed effect modelling, and I'm using `lmer()` in R.
My question is regarding the number of observations. Is there any assumption or rule of thumb?
I have tens of thousands of observations and want to understand the random effect of four different variables.

It looks quite computationally heavy and my RStudio Server is crashing before finishing anything. :(

I've tried the following code in R:

```
 reml <- lmer(Target ~ V1 * V2 * V3 * V4 + (1|V1) + (1|V2) + (1|V3) + (1|V4) , df, REML = T)
```

and got this:

```
Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) :
```

too large a matrix for LINPACK

I tried simplifying the model a bit, just to see if it goes somewhere:

```
reml <- lmer(Target ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + (1|V1) + (1|V2) + (1|V3) + (1|V4) , df, REML = T)
```

but now I get a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues
3: Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -9.1e-06
```

Is the dataset too big? Should I be concerned about this convergence issue?

Comment: Yes, the design matrix appears to be too big. You could try package MCMCglmm or go Bayesian and use `rstanarm::stan_glmer` (work well even with default priors).

Comment: Also if your V1-V4 are categorical (nominal) predictors, you are entering them twice into the model here (V1 as a categorical predictor is equivalent to (1|V1) ). The error doesn't seem to be about that though.

Comment: Yes, good point. A fixed effects variable shouldn't be simultaneously be the grouping variable of a random effect. The model doesn't make sense at all. If you create a sensible model, the issue will probably be solved.

Comment: So, apart to going MCMCglmm or Baeysian, are my formula off? I want to understand what the impact of each variable on the target (dependent variable) is. I want to understand the interactions as well, but as the thing was not getting anywhere I was trying to reduce the 'complexity' by simplifying the formula.

Comment: Yes, it's off. You shouldn't enter same variables as predictors and random effect grouping variables. You have to decide which provide more relevant information re: your research questions (sounds like you're interested in their fixed effects more). The interactions are (likely) not the problem here.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/632208/what-is-the-procedure-to-specify-a-random-effects-design-matrix/632212#632212

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand you are asking "Is there an upper limit for the number of observations beyond which a linear mixed effects model can't be fit?"

The answer is: Yes, there are computational limits. In particular, memory demand can exceed available memory and matrices can become too large to be processed. However, hitting these limits is rare and usually indicates a misspecified model. One advantage of mixed-effects models is that they can handle predictors that are categorical with many levels by modelling them as random effects. That needs far fewer parameters than modelling them as fixed effects where they need to be dummy-encoded (many model functions in R do that automatically), which potentially results in a huge design matrix.

Your model creates such a fixed-effects model with a massive design matrix and than redundantly models the same predictors as random intercepts. Doing so is not sensible: Either `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, `V4` are fixed effects or they are ID variables of random effects. They can't be both. I assume they are all categorical, which means including all interactions is the cause for the design matrix being so large, which results in the first model fit erroring. The second model doesn't include the interactions, resulting in a more reasonably sized design matrix (but it can still be quite large). It fails because it can't split the same effect into a fixed and a random effect.

Comment: Thanks! Learning with mistakes. I re-thought what I had and actually, two variables could be joined. Now I use a simpler formula: `Target ~ V1*V2 + (1|V3)` which now I have a lot of results to understand. I've been following this: https://mspeekenbrink.github.io/sdam-r-companion/linear-mixed-effects-models.html#obtaining-p-values-with-afexmixed but would not mind some direction in what I should be reading as well.

Answer (score 10):

I will add my two cents as the two questions have very different answers, and the [accepted answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/634783/5739) only explains those very briefly. One assumption I would have to make is that all of those variables are categorical/factors, and some have many levels.

1. The *too large matrix* error is coming from the fixed effects side of the model -- the four-way interaction `V1*V2*V3*V4` probably identifies every observation in the data set -- check what `length(unique(df$V1)) * length(unique(df$V2)) * length(unique(df$V3)) * length(unique(df$V4))` is. In the $(X'X)^{-1}$ fixed part of the regression model, you end up with the $n \times n$ matrix. A $10^4 \times 10^4$ matrix is sizeable (~800Mb) but it should not be breaking the linear algebra compute libraries. A 50K $\times$ 50K matrix is 20Gb and would stretch the memory of most laptops. There may be a version of a mixed model with sparse matrices -- the said matrix has only one non-zero off-diagonal entry in each row/column so the storage does not have to be 20Gb, it can be 1Mb... but its inverse will likely get dense.
2. The second error comes from model identification. You are asking to estimate the effect of each variable twice, once as a fixed effect, and the second time as the random effect. Once you have taken out the fixed effect of `V1`, the residuals with respect to that variable are exactly zero. The variance of the term `(1|V1)` is estimated to be zero, the log and the inverse of that variance that go into the likelihood blow it to infinity, and when the Hessian is numerically evaluated, the difference of several infinities produce round off errors making the result a matrix that is not positive definite. (A better syntax parser would have detected the presence of the variable as both a fixed and a random effect and would have issued a more informative warning.)

My overall conclusion is that the OP is not prepared to tackle the mixed models on their own. I would suggest seeking help of an appropriate professional consulting statistician at a nearby university or [online](https://ww2.amstat.org/consultantdirectory/index.cfm?fuseaction=searchresults).

Comment: Yes, the variables are categorical, and some have many levels. I'm seeking someone that really knows this. Thanks for your answer. It was helpful.